# Why is this NOT NULL to NULL migration triggering lots of I/O operations?

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL table, with 120M rows and a size of about 120GB:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `impressions` (
  `session_uuid` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `survey_uuid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_uuid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `is_test` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `impressions_survey_uuid_session_uuid_user_uuid_index` (`survey_uuid`,`session_uuid`,`user_uuid`),
  KEY `impressions_created_at_index` (`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I see that this data migration is taking more than 6 hours (on a decent RDS instance where I was able to run more complex migrations) because is doing lots of I/O operations. Why does it have to do so many operations? The only thing I'm changing here is the NULL optionality and the default value.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `impressions` CHANGE COLUMN `user_uuid` `user_uuid` VARCHAR(255) null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the nullability of a column changes the structure of the row in InnoDB. A row stored in InnoDB has a bitmap for each nullable column, to indicate whether that column is in fact NULL on the given row. If you change the nullability of a column, you have changed the length of the bitmap. Therefore every row must be rewritten to a new set of pages.

Changing only the DEFAULT is a metadata-only change.

I've made the mistake of running an ALTER TABLE that should've been a metadata-only change, but I forgot to match the nullability of the original column, and so my ALTER TABLE became a table restructure and took a long time.

If you have to do such changes in MySQL, I suggest you look at one of the open-source online schema change tools: [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) or [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost). I've used the former tool to manage many long-running schema changes in production. It usually makes the operation take a little bit longer, but that's not a problem because the table can still be used for both reading and writing while the schema change is in progress.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time in writing this great answer!
Luckily, for this particular case, the table doesn't get locked and I can still read and write to it, but I'll have a look at the tools you suggested when I'll need it!

Comment: There are other advantages to the online schema change tools. For example, with regular ALTER TABLE, the alter can't start on a replica instance until it's finished on the source instance. But with online schema change tools, they run in parallel, so the change is done on the replica almost immediately.